# Gnuplot: How to add yerrorbars into a histogram that is plotted using "newhistogram" for several clustered histograms?

Tags: gnuplot, bar-chart, histogram, errorbar

I have plotted a clustered set of data into the same plot of a histogram. Since I have several clustered sets of data I used the practical "newhistogram" command. It works out well but I have not found out how to add the yerrorbars yet? I would be glad someone being familiar with how errobars can be added to the "newhistogram" command.

I have already tried adding the simple command "w yerrorbars" including the related reference to the column of the datafile but then the plot only contained the yerrorbars (including the mean in the middle) but the bar Chart was not presented anymore.

```
...
set datafile separator ','
...
set style data histogram
set style histogram errobars linewidth 1
set bars 0.5

plot newhistogram "Multi-crew ops", 'example.dat' index 0 u 3:xtic(2) t 'Departure', 'example.dat' index 0 u 5:xtic(2) t 'Cruise', 'example.dat' index 0 u 7:xtic(2) t 'Arrival', \
    newhistogram "Reduced-crew ops", 'example.dat' index 1 u 3:xtic(2) t 'Departure', 'example.dat' index 1 u 5:xtic(2) t 'Cruise' , 'example.dat' index 1 u 7:xtic(2) t 'Arrival', \
    newhistogram "Acceptance of crewing-ops", 'example.dat' index 2 u 9:xtic(1) axes x1y2 t 'All phases'
```

This did not work out:
...

```
plot newhistogram "Multi-crew ops", 'example.dat' index 0 u 3:4:xtic(2) t 'Departure' w yerrorbars, ...
```

This did not work out either:

```
set datafile separator ','

set style data histogram
set bars 0.5
set style histogram errobars linewidth 1

plot newhistogram "Multi-crew ops", 'example.dat' index 0 u 3:4:xtic(2) t 'Departure', 'example.dat' index 0 u 5:6:xtic(2) t 'Cruise', 'example.dat' index 0 u 7:8:xtic(2) t 'Arrival', \
    newhistogram "Reduced-crew ops", 'example.dat' index 1 u 3:4:xtic(2) t 'Departure', 'example.dat' index 1 u 5:6:xtic(2) t 'Cruise' , 'example.dat' index 1 u 7:8:xtic(2) t 'Arrival', \
    newhistogram "Acceptance of crewing-ops", 'example.dat' index 2 u 9:10:xtic(1) axes x1y2 t 'All phases'
```

Comment: If your answer solved your problem, please accept your own answer indicating that the question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the command you show is that only one column of input data (the y value) is provided for each bar.  In order to add errorbars you need a second input column that holds the delta-y value.  For example where you have

```
   'example.dat' index 0 u 3:xtic(2) t 'Departure'
```

You should have instead

```
   'example.dat' index 0 u 3:N:xtic(2) t 'Departure'
```

Where N is the column holding the error values.  If the errors are to be calculated from a function rather than being read from an input column, it would look like this

```
   'example.dat' index 0 u 3:(func(something)):xtic(2) t 'Departure'
```

Comment: (1)  there is a typo:  'errobars' instead of 'errorbars'   (2) This is because the command in (1) was rejected, so the style was not set to errorbars.

Comment: Okay, this works out as well. Thanks. Hence, newhistogram can be combined with all usual gnuplot commands.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found an answer how to integrate errorbars into gnuplot's newhistogram command. The style has to be set to *histogram cluster*. Even the adaption of colors etc. is possible:

```
...
set style histogram cluster gap 2 errorbars linewidth 2
set style data histogram
...
plot newhistogram "condition 1", 'example.dat' index 0 u 3:4:xtic(2) t 'Departure' lw 2 lc rgb "#32CD32", 'example.dat' index 0 u 5:6:xtic(2) t 'Cruise' lw 2 lc rgb "#6745FF", 'example.dat' index 0 u 7:8:xtic(2) t 'Arrival' lw 2 lc rgb "#FFA057", \
    newhistogram "condition 2", 'example.dat' index 1 u 3:4:xtic(2) lw 2 lc rgb "#32CD32" notitle, 'example.dat' index 1 u 5:6:xtic(2) lw 2 lc rgb "#6745FF" notitle, 'example.dat' index 1 u 7:8:xtic(2) lw 2 lc rgb "#FFA057" notitle, \
    newhistogram "condition 3", 'example.dat' index 2 u 9:10:xtic(1) axes x1y2 t 'All phases' lw 2 lc rgb "#A19CB8"
```